# SSH to Vmware virtual machine with NAT network

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, iptables, vmware-player

right now I am able to `ssh` to host over internet and `ssh` from host to the virtual machine. What I want to do is `ssh` directly to the Guest machine from outside.

I tried to do this using `iptables`:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m tcp -p tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.130.128:22
```

And also opened this related ports on `UFW`:

```
ufw allow routed
ufw allow outgoing
ufw deny incoming
ufw allow 2222/tcp
```

After reloading firewalls, remote `ssh` will freeze on `debug1: Connecting to x.x.x.x [x.x.x.x] port 2222` and using `tcpdump -i vmnet8 'port 22'` I can see this:

```
listening on vmnet8, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
18:56:03.002790 IP x.x.x.x.13203 > y.y.y.y.ssh: Flags [S], seq 1077492285, win 29200, options [mss 1260,sackOK,TS val 1388564 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
18:56:03.003235 IP y.y.y.y.ssh > x.x.x.x.13203: Flags [S.], seq 3535035554, ack 1077492286, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 4,nop,nop,TS val 307333897 ecr 1388564,sackOK,eol], length 0
18:56:03.003290 IP x.x.x.x.13203 > y.y.y.y.ssh: Flags [R], seq 1077492286, win 32767, length 0
18:56:03.996287 IP x.x.x.x.13203 > y.y.y.y.ssh: Flags [S], seq 1077492285, win 29200, options [mss 1260,sackOK,TS val 1388664 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
18:56:03.996770 IP y.y.y.y.ssh > x.x.x.x.13203: Flags [S.], seq 1749343118, ack 1077492286, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 4,nop,nop,TS val 307334888 ecr 1388664,sackOK,eol], length 0
18:56:03.996841 IP x.x.x.x.13203 > y.y.y.y.ssh: Flags [R], seq 1077492286, win 32767, length 0
18:56:05.997104 IP x.x.x.x.13203 > y.y.y.y.ssh: Flags [S], seq 1077492285, win 29200, options [mss 1260,sackOK,TS val 1388864 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
18:56:06.001310 IP y.y.y.y.ssh > x.x.x.x.13203: Flags [S.], seq 3571006762, ack 1077492286, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 4,nop,nop,TS val 307336889 ecr 1388864,sackOK,eol], length 0
18:56:06.001344 IP x.x.x.x.13203 > y.y.y.y.ssh: Flags [R], seq 1077492286, win 32767, length 0
18:56:10.006741 IP x.x.x.x.13203 > y.y.y.y.ssh: Flags [S], seq 1077492285, win 29200, options [mss 1260,sackOK,TS val 1389265 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
18:56:10.007142 IP y.y.y.y.ssh > x.x.x.x.13203: Flags [S.], seq 1524745855, ack 1077492286, win 65535, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 4,nop,nop,TS val 307340890 ecr 1389265,sackOK,eol], length 0
18:56:10.007217 IP x.x.x.x.13203 > y.y.y.y.ssh: Flags [R], seq 1077492286, win 32767, length 0
```

`tcpdump` on my `MacOS` guest will result the same.

- HOST: Ubuntu 14.04
- GUEST: mac os mavericks
- virtualization platform: Vmware workstation 11

### Update:

This is `ufw` log message (log high):

```
Jun 21 09:47:44 srv05-crawler kernel: [518567.737815] [UFW AUDIT] IN=eth0 OUT=vmnet8 MAC=00:25:90:ef:aa:a0:00:24:c4:c0:d3:40:08:00 SRC=x.x.x.x DST=192.168.130.128 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=51 ID=15454 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=20039 DPT=22 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Jun 21 09:47:44 srv05-crawler kernel: [518567.737828] [UFW ALLOW] IN=eth0 OUT=vmnet8 MAC=00:25:90:ef:aa:a0:00:24:c4:c0:d3:40:08:00 SRC=x.x.x.x DST=192.168.130.128 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=51 ID=15454 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=20039 DPT=22 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Jun 21 09:47:45 srv05-crawler kernel: [518568.733572] [UFW AUDIT] IN=eth0 OUT=vmnet8 MAC=00:25:90:ef:aa:a0:00:24:c4:c0:d3:40:08:00 SRC=x.x.x.x DST=192.168.130.128 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=51 ID=15455 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=20039 DPT=22 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 
Jun 21 09:47:45 srv05-crawler kernel: [518568.733592] [UFW ALLOW] IN=eth0 OUT=vmnet8 MAC=00:25:90:ef:aa:a0:00:24:c4:c0:d3:40:08:00 SRC=x.x.x.x DST=192.168.130.128 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=51 ID=15455 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=20039 DPT=22 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0a
```

And I used this commands to get dropped packets logs:

```
iptables -N LOGGING
iptables -A INPUT -j LOGGING
iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOGGING
iptables -A LOGGING -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPT Drops: " --log-level 4
iptables -A LOGGING -j DROP
```

But I couldn't trace any `dropped` package.

### Update 2:

iptables config as some friends asked for:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sun Jun 21 16:46:49 2015
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1363:113716]
:INPUT ACCEPT [39:2210]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [3135:202553]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [3146:203213]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2222 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.130.128:22
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jun 21 16:46:49 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sun Jun 21 16:46:49 2015
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:LOGGING - [0:0]
:fail2ban-ssh - [0:0]
:ufw-after-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-after-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-output - [0:0]
:ufw-logging-allow - [0:0]
:ufw-logging-deny - [0:0]
:ufw-not-local - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-input - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-output - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-input - [0:0]
:ufw-skip-to-policy-output - [0:0]
:ufw-track-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-track-input - [0:0]
:ufw-track-output - [0:0]
:ufw-user-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-user-input - [0:0]
:ufw-user-limit - [0:0]
:ufw-user-limit-accept - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-user-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-user-output - [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22022 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-reject-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-track-input
-A INPUT -j LOGGING
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-reject-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-track-forward
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-reject-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-track-output
-A OUTPUT -j LOGGING
-A LOGGING -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPtables dropped: "
-A LOGGING -j DROP
-A fail2ban-ssh -j RETURN
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-logging-input -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-before-forward -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 4 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -j ufw-user-forward
-A ufw-before-input -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 4 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -m udp --sport 67 --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-not-local
-A ufw-before-input -d 224.0.0.251/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -d 239.255.255.250/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 1900 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-user-input
-A ufw-before-output -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -j ufw-user-output
-A ufw-logging-allow -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "
-A ufw-logging-deny -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j RETURN
-A ufw-logging-deny -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type MULTICAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-not-local -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-forward -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-input -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-output -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-forward -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-forward -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22022 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2222 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-limit -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
-A ufw-user-limit -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A ufw-user-limit-accept -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Jun 21 16:46:49 2015
```

And `ufw status numbered`:

```
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 22022/tcp                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere
[ 2] 2222/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere
```

Comment: Does your virtual machine have direct access to the internet? If not, you will need to use masquerading.

Comment: @Shahinism: more interesting than your `tcpdump` output would be the firewall logs. Even though your VM may respond to the request, who's to say the host doesn't drop it on its way out? Also, I presume IPv4 forwarding is enabled in your system? DNAT would work both ways, though, but only if the packet is let through on its way out.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq Yes it does, as I said I can receive ssh request on guest device itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**-> Jump to the update**

As mentioned in the `man ufw` found [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man8/ufw.8.html) I would change the appearance of rule 4 to come before rule 3.

> Rule  ordering  is  important  and the first match wins. Therefore when
>    adding rules, add the more specific rules first with more general rules
>    later.

First allow incomming tcp on 2222, and route to 192.168.130.128:22
Then deny all incoming.

Don't know if its important, but in the man page the routing rule looks

```
ufw route allow 2222/tcp to 192.168.130.128 port 22
```

**Update**

#### Short version

You told `iptables` to add a `PREROUTING` rule to your `nat table`.
The missing part is:

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------
# After DNAT, the packets are routed via the filter table's
# FORWARD chain.
# Connections on port 22 to the target machine on the private
# network must be allowed.
#---------------------------------------------------------------
# The `\` masks the `linebreak` in the `bash command`
# You can `copy & paste` all the lines at once

# From the manual
# Changing to specific IP and Interfaces  
# being:
# `eth0` your host adapter and
# `vmnet8` your guest adapter
```

This is the connection into the target machine:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -i eth0 -o vmnet8 -d 192.168.130.128 \
    --dport 22 --sport 2222 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

And these are the filter from `host interface` to your `guest interface`
and vice versa.

```
iptables -A FORWARD -t filter -o eth0 -m state \
         --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

iptables -A FORWARD -t filter -i vmnet8 -m state \
         --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

#### Remark

First, I would get familiar with saving and reloading `iptables`.

Then I would change option `-A` to `-I`. This will put the rules into first position.

And I would think about changing `-A` to `-C`, because `iptables` will prompt for eventually missing parameter.

At least I would `-Z` zero the counter of all rules and see what happens after implementing new rules.

Keeping the answer right on track

You asked for all of this as a `ufw manual`. But if we fix your issue with the `back-end` then `ufw front-end` will be easy.

Source for this update was found [here](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch14_:_Linux_Firewalls_Using_iptables#Checking_The_Firewall_Logs) and license was [CC BY-NC-ND 2.5](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/2.5/legalcode)
and [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/3/html/Reference_Guide/s1-iptables-options.html).

Comment: `ufw` is but a frontend to `iptables`. Looking at the command I'd say the outcome in the respective netfilter table/chain will be nearly identical.

Comment: @0xC0000022L didn't know that, but what do you think about the ordering?

Comment: best guess I would have made myself. The `tcpdump` output is misleading on the local system. What would be interesting are the firewall logs.

Comment: @MarcoM.vonHagen I even disabled `ufw` and nothing changed in result.

Comment: @Shahinism as [0xC0000022L](http://superuser.com/users/68747/0xc0000022l) mentioned, `ufw` is a frontend to `iptables`. Disabling the frontend after use will not reset your `iptables`. Show us the output of `iptables-save > output.txt` explained [here](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch14_:_Linux_Firewalls_Using_iptables#Fedora.27s_iptables_Rule_Generator "Linux Firewalls and iptables").

Comment: @Shahinism go back to `ufw` and show us the output of `ufw status numbered`. This will give us the chance to re-arrange the occurency of your rules to make things work.

Comment: @MarcoM.vonHagen Thank you for helping. I added those data as you suggested to original post.