# Ssh Access to VMware Virtual Machine(NAT) From Host

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vmware, putty, nat

I need to `ssh` into NAT based VMware Virtual Machines from host. What's the *minimum* requirement to do that?

At first, it seems impossible to me, as NAT VMs have internal IP addresses (10.20.xxx), whereas my host is on the 192.168.xxx subnet. Then from this answer, 
[Can't access VMware virtual machine through SSH](https://superuser.com/questions/308187/cant-access-vmware-virtual-machine-through-ssh), it seems possible, but it only said *"I have configured NAT port forwarding"*, without further details.

So, What'd the *minimum* requirements/steps be
to be able to `ssh` into NAT based VMware VMs from host?
Will the NAT VM always get the same internal IP address?
How can I give my VM a host name for my ssh client (putty) to access from host?
How to access more than one NAT VMs from host?

PS, Further details, I am doing Putty SSH under Windows 7 (Host) into Ubuntu (Guest) under VMware Workstation. PPS, I had always been using Bridged networking for this case, everything was working fine, until now, my Bridged networking VM can't get an IP any more (neither dynamic nor static work now due to our pathetic network access rule).